# Django model : filtering and counting

Tags: python, django, count, many-to-many, models

I have the following issue :

My db contains a list of Movies, a list of Criterions which all have a list of possible Choices, and Users can all give an Opinion (i.e. select a Choice) for each couple (Criterion, Movie).

```
class Movie(Model):
    ...

class Criterion(Model):
    ...

class Choice(Model):
    criterion = ForeignKey(Criterion)
    ...

class Opinion(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    movie = ForeignKey(Movie)
    choice = ForeignKey(Choice)
```

I already have solved the issue of uniqueness between tuple (user, movie, choice__criterion) but now here is what I want to do :
Given a choice, I want to list all movies for which this choice is mostly choosed by users (Opinion) AND I want to do it in an unique query without having to write my own SQL query AND I want to do it without redundancy in my database.

Do you think it's possible ? If yes, how ?

ps : About the no redundancy : I want no redundancy first because it's bad, but mainly because I haven't found how to "clean" a ManyToMany field (when I added a ManyToMany "best_choices" to my Movie model in order to keep for each movie the list of prefered choices for each criterion).

Comment: Can you update the models code above to what relations your models have with each other?

Comment: Hmm. I thought is was transparent since I used same name as Models for ForeignKey.     I worked on it all the night and the only solution I found is to make it in two sub queries : one count distinct pk for (movie, choice) in Opinion table, the a python script select the best one for each (movie, criterion) then select movies that match required choices, and finaly the second query collect movies'data. (Example on http://c9.io/voblivion > workspace "django-test")

Comment: imho it is not possible using just aggregations/aggregations, it is however doable in postgresql SQL.